# SONARQUBE lcov import error - Could not resolve 1 file paths

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, lcov

I am getting the below error whenever I try to import lcov report in to SONAR

```
15:00:17.230 WARN: Could not resolve 1 file paths in [/opt/app/workload/jenkins_25172/data/jobs/DEV02/workspace/coverage/lcov.info], first unresolved path: /opt/app/workload/jenkins_25172/data/jobs/DEV02/workspace/common/actions/actionCreators.js
```

SONAR properties:

```
sonar.login=**
sonar.password=**
sonar.verbose=true 
sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=.
sonar.projectBaseDir=/opt/app/workload/jenkins_25172/data/jobs/DEV02/workspace/
sonar.inclusions=coverage/**/*
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.projectKey=test2 
sonar.projectName=test2 
sonar.projectVersion=version1 
sonar.branch=test
sonar.att.view.type=dev 
sonar.tattletale.enabled=false
```

Any input to fix this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Still unresolved? What sonarqube version you're at? I'm on the same problem with sonarqube 5.6 - still trying to make it in.

Comment: Having the same issue and the coverage displayed on my server ends up being `0.0%`

Answer (score -1):

**Someone looking for the same solution can try following:**

> reportPath to reportPaths

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

OR (in case of tyescript)

```
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/lcov.info
```